# Juntar dois array do banco e excluir valores repetidos

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Preciso de ajuda urgente, estou fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados em vários array diferente. Quando as informações com "implode" e pego de novo com "explode", porém, recebo valores repetidos e eu queria a mesma função do "SELECT DISTINCT". Alguém sabe como resolver?
Código:

```
<h4>Cores</h4>
            <?php          
            while($row_mestre = mysqli_fetch_assoc($matrizMestre))
            {
                $CorNormal = $row_mestre["CorProduto"];
                if(strpos($CorNormal,",") == FALSE)
                {
                    $CorFinal = $CorNormal;
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="CorConsulta[]" value="$CorFinal[$j]"/>'. $CorFinal.'<br/>';
                }
                else
                {
                    $CorFinal = explode(",",$CorNormal);
                        if (is_array($CorFinal))
                        {   
                            for($j=0;$j<sizeof($CorFinal);$j++)
                            {   
                                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="CorConsulta[]" value="$CorFinal[$j]"/>'. $CorFinal[$j].'<br/>';
                            }
                        }

                 }     
            }  
            ?>
        </div>
```

Imagens da tabela e de como é mostrado
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcqW5.jpg

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que você está salvando os valores separados por vírgula? Acredito que seu caso é pertinente de uma [normalização de dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados)

Comment: Estou fazendo isso porque na loja, o mesmo produto pode ter mais do que uma cor. Nao vejo outra forma de fazer isso

Comment: Dei uma estudada e consegui fazer a normalização. Foi uma dica pequena mas ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o  [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-unique.php) possa lhe ajudar após a aplicação do método explode:

```
$CorFinal = explode(",",$CorNormal);
$arrayFinal = array_unique($CorFinal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo usar uma combinação das funções [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) (para juntar dois ou mais arrays e retornar um array) e array_unique (que retorna os valores únicos dentro de uma array.

Primeiro eu uso a função array_merge para juntar os arrays:

```
<?php


$primeiro_array = ["Laranja", "Limão", "Banana"];

$segundo_array = ["Laranja", "Limão", "Banana"];

$terceiro_array = array_merge($primeiro_array, $segundo_array);
```

Depois eu excluo os valores repetidos com [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
$resultado = array_unique($terceiro_array);

print_r($resultado);
```

Resultado:

```
Array (
    [0] => Laranja
    [1] => Limão
    [2] => Banana
)
```

**Observação** Os teste foram feitos usando PHP 7.

Answer (score -1):

O jeito que eu consegui e deu certo foi esse:

```
            <?php          
            while($row_mestre = mysqli_fetch_assoc($matrizMestre))
            {
                $Cor = $row_mestre["CorProduto"];
                if(strlen($Cor)>0)
                {
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="CoresdeProduto[]" value="' .$Cor. '"/>'. $Cor .'<br/>';
                }
            }  
            ?>
```

Eu faço um INSERT normal sem as cores:

```
$queryEnvio = "INSERT INTO tabela (IdProduto,NomeProduto) VALUES (null, '$NomeProduto')";
mysqli_query($conn,$comando);
```

Aqui eu seleciono o ultimo valor inserido pelo ID e a Cor de uma outra tabela só de cores

```
    $SelectProduto = "SELECT IdProduto,CorProduto FROM produto,corproduto ORDER BY IdProduto DESC LIMIT 1";
    $Select = mysqli_query($conn,$SelectProduto);
    $linha_select = mysqli_fetch_array($Select);
```

Pego o ID da tabel, as cores selecionadas pelo usuário e vejo a quantidade:

```
    $IdProduto= $linha_select["IdProduto"];
    $arrayCor = $_POST["CorProduto"];
    $TamanhoCor= count($arrayCor);
```

Faço um laço de repetição pra inserir todas as cores de acordo com o ID usando a 1FN

```
    for($x=0;$x<$tamanho;$x++)
    {
      $gravar = "INSERT INTO cod_produtos VALUES ($IdProduto,'$arrayCor[$x]')";
    }
    $conn->query($gravar);
```

Comment: Se você quiser pegar o último ID inserido, use a seguinte função: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php